# Why does this python function not work if I wrap it in a def() call?

Tags: python

This code works if it isn't wrapped in the function duplicateDel(). I'm sorry but I'm very new to python and I simply cannot figure out why this stops working within the function.

```
import sys
import csv

def duplicateDel():
    f1 = csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rb'))
    writer = csv.writer(open("file2.csv", "wb"))
    x = set()
    for row in f1:
        if row[3] not in x:
            writer.writerow(row)
            x.add( row[3] )
```

Comment: Because you're never *calling* the function, just defining it...?!

Comment: `def`ining a function tells Python *how* to do something. It doesn't tell Python to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Wrapping"** it into `def`, means that you are declaring your function to futher usage, so, in order to use it you need call it. In your case, just add `duplicateDel()`

```
def duplicateDel():
    f1 = csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rb'))
    writer = csv.writer(open("file2.csv", "wb"))
    x = set()
    for row in f1:
        if row[3] not in x:
            writer.writerow(row)
            x.add( row[3] )

duplicateDel()
```

I think you should read a bit more about how functions works in python. Take a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)